# how to get google api URL content with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=London&destinations=drove&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false

how to use data of this URL in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

With native js, here is the code to do a get request and get the json data (in xhr.responseText)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=London&destinations=drove&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false';
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
}
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way to do it would be with a popular, open-source library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) which has an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method that will retrieve that data from Google asynchronously, which you can then parse and process in your app further using javascript.

The code will look something like

```js
$.ajax('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' +
  'London&destinations=drove&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false', {
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      // Process the returned JSON contaied in 'response' here.
    }
  });
```

Also worth noting is that you will get an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error from the request, which will prevent it from returning any data unless you also mention your API key in the query string (appended to the URL with an `&`).

I'd encourage you to read up further on AJAX and APIs. I believe that would be quite helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link.Hope this will guide you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Comment: atif bro I did this method but that is bit lengthy. I just want the driving distance between two locations after that I have to store and sort and get shortest between many locations. Thats why I am using this short method.